# Solve for real value of $x$: $|x^2 -2x -3| > |x^2 +7x -13|$

Tags: inequality

Here I have a question:

Solve for real value of $x$:
$$|x^2 -2x -3| > |x^2 +7x -13|$$

I got the answer as $x = (-\infty, \frac{1}{4}(-5-3\sqrt{17}))$ and $x=(\frac{10}{9},\frac{1}{4}(3\sqrt{17}-5)$

Please verify it if it is correct or not. Thanks

Comment: Compare it on multiple intervals: where both positive, both negative, and one is positive while the other one is negative.

Comment: Means is more important than the end. So, please share your approach.

Comment: I solved it by drawing the graphs of two parabolic equations and then by observing the graphs, the answer was found out. But i want to know. is there any other approach also?

Comment: [There you go](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=|x^2+-2x+-3|+%3E+|x^2+%2B7x+-13|). Since your answer is correct, there's not much point in the question to begin with (there might have been, if you had posted your complete solution and asked certain things about it, like if there's a better way, etc).

Answer (score 6):

**hint**: Use $|A| > |B| \iff A^2 > B^2 \iff (A-B)(A+B) > 0$. Apply this property to $A = x^2-2x-3, B = x^2+7x-13$

Comment: Hm. Interesting tactic.

Comment: @copper.hat: Your argument is the continuation of where NotALoner left off, no? (+1 to this and your answer!)

Comment: Well, I used brute force to get the zeros, the above approach gets them 'for free'. The above is a cute trick.

Answer (score 2):

Brute force (as I am wont to do):

Look at where $(x^2-2x-3)^2 - (x^2+7x-13)^2 = -(9x-10)(2x^2+5x-16)$ is strictly positive.

The zeroes are ${10 \over 9}$ and ${1 \over 4} (-5 \pm 3 \sqrt{17})$.

Since the leading coefficient is $-1$, we see that the answer is
$(-\infty,{1 \over 4} (-5 - 3 \sqrt{17})) \cup ({10 \over 9}, {1 \over 4} (-5 + 3 \sqrt{17}))$.

Comment: I think it is $-5$ in place of $5$